# glxBadDrawable when using bgfx

Tags: c++, sdl, glfw, bgfx

When using the following BGFX code:

```cpp
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include <bgfx/bgfx.h>

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello, bgfx!", NULL, NULL);
    
    
    bgfx::Init bgfxInit;
    bgfxInit.type = bgfx::RendererType::Count; // Automatically choose a renderer.
    bgfxInit.resolution.width = 800;
    bgfxInit.resolution.height = 600;
    bgfxInit.resolution.reset = BGFX_RESET_VSYNC;
    bgfx::init(bgfxInit);
}
```

A black openGL window pops up and appears fine for a second, however, a GLXBadDrawable error then pops up. I do not know what the cause of this error is, and the other question has no answers and has not been active for some time now.

I believe that this is not an issue with the code, but rather my machine, however, I may be wrong.

I currently have a Lenovo T400 laptop, with a Core 2 Duo P9500. I have 2 built-in GPUs, a Mobile 4 Series Chipset integrated graphics chip, along with an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470. I am also running Artix Linux with the 6.0.7-artix1-1 kernel. I also am using the glfw-x11 and glfw packages if that helps, along with the i3-gaps window manager.

I have also attempted to use SDL2 instead of GLFW, and the same issue occurs. However, for GLFW a black window shows up, while in SDL2, a transparent(?) window instead shows up. Searching the github issues page also yielded no results.

Answer (score 0):

Adding platformData solved it for me

```
bgfx::Init bgfxInit;
bgfxInit.type = bgfx::RendererType::Count; // Automatically choose a renderer.
bgfxInit.resolution.width = 800;
bgfxInit.resolution.height = 600;
bgfxInit.resolution.reset = BGFX_RESET_VSYNC;
#if BX_PLATFORM_LINUX || BX_PLATFORM_BSD
    bgfxInit.platformData.ndt = glfwGetX11Display();
    bgfxInit.platformData.nwh = (void*)(uintptr_t)glfwGetX11Window(window);
#elif BX_PLATFORM_OSX
    bgfxInit.platformData.nwh = glfwGetCocoaWindow(window);
#elif BX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    bgfxInit.platformData.nwh = glfwGetWin32Window(window);
#endif
bgfx::init(bgfxInit);
```